# Groovy scripts for Jenkins automation, where to store and how to run from jenkins cli?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have coded a script to automate some process in Jenkins. Until now I have been using script console to try and run my code. Now what I am trying to achieve is to upload the script file in a parent job workspace and run it from Jenkins CLI command. Is it possible to execute groovy scripts from job workspace, or is there some better approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that works with Jenkins CLI but you can predefine scripts using *Manage Jenkins > Managed files* or *Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Global Pipeline Libraries*.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Shared Library Feature](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/).
Upload your scripts into a VCS like Github/Bitbucket and use Jenkins-Jobs to execute them. They are available for all projects/jobs.
If you use scripts for administrative tasks, I think the Jenkins CLI is a best place to execute. Use cron jobs for repetitive tasks.